# Delivered messages in Twilio Logs but it's not actually delivered

Tags: twilio

I have a local number in the US, I tried to send a SMS message to a US phone number, and the message is received, but when I try to send a message to Saudi Arabia, I can't receive any messages, I tried to text several numbers from several Carriers, it does not work. I tried to send a message from my phone number (Saudi) to the US number (Twilio) and it's received.

[image] here is the image with message details

why I can't send message to phone numbers in Saudi Arabia?

Comment: Check this table: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183068-Twilio-international-phone-number-availability-and-their-capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I recommend checking the [SMS guidelines for Saudi Arabia](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/sa). Some highlights include:

> Saudi Arabian networks have implemented strong filtering. These filters will block most messages which come from numeric sender IDs, messages which contain objectionable content, and messages which contain URLs. Furthermore, if a message is sent that has identical content to a recent message, this message will be blocked.
>
> We strongly encourage customers who wish to deliver messages to users in Saudi Arabia to use a preregistered Sender ID.

I see that you're sending verification codes. If this is for phone verification or two factor authentication, can I suggest using our [Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/verify) or [Two Factor Authentication](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/authy) APIs? They are already optimised for sending codes all around the world, and should make building that feature easier for you.

Otherwise I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can advise you further on sending messages to Saudi Arabia.

Comment: I just rephrased my message and it works, for some reason some messages would be filtered by carriers and blocked.